# When should describe() and test_that() be used?

Tags: r, testing, testthat

The `testthat` package in `R` offers two ways to structure your tests:

- `describe()` is a BDD implementation, where you give a "description of the feature". Within this, you have several sets of specifications called `it` blocks. These contain the actual assertions / `expect` calls, and have their own description, which is concatenated to the feature description in the printout if a test fails
- `test_that()` takes a "test name", followed by code for the test.

The idea seems to be that `describe()` is used for big features/objects, whereas `test_that()` is used for "smaller, self-contained" sets of functionality, but I'm not sure that I understand the distinction, since I thought denoting "features" is what `context()` is used for, and features are supposed to be self-contained anyway.

In the `describe()` documentation, we are told the following:

> Use describe to verify that you implement the right things and use test_that() to ensure you do the things right.

This is a very brief distinction that I lack the contextual knowledge to understand. Hadley Wickham's R packages book doesn't mention `describe()` at all, so I can't look there for clarification either.

My guess is that, roughly, `describe()` is for acceptance tests, and `test_that()` is for unit tests. What am I missing by using this assumption, and what is the intended use difference?